# Is it possible in row in Dashboard to have an alternate color using Google App Maker?

Tags: css, google-app-maker

All the codes that I've research are not acceptable in Google App Maker. Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Sample image below: 
Ctto
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/50E5W

Comment: Include any code in the question itself. Please see: [ask], [mcve]. Have you actually done anything yourself to try to resolve this? Do you expect people to spoon-feed you the code?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really really bad. You should include at least a code snippet of what you've tried so far. Anyways, put the following css at the **Page style** level of where your table is and you should be good to go.

```
.app-ListTableRow:nth-child(even){
  background-color: mistyrose;
}

.app-ListTableRow:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Will do that in my next question. 

I tried your suggestion but it did not work. 

.app-Dashboard-Table6Body:nth-child(even){
  background-color: red;
}

.app-_Dashboard-Table6Body:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: blue;
}

Comment: @AngkasQuintos No, You didn't try my suggestion. Literally, use the exact same code I posted. Don't change anything except for the colors.